# Retrieving custom field values using Jira POST api (curl)

Tags: jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get values for a handful of custom fields using the Jira post API. I'm reasonably confident the curl request part is correct. However, regardless of what i change in the search parameters I get the same result and it won't give me any information on the fields I need.

I suspect its something to do with expanding fields but I can't find anything on how to do this when using POST rather than GET, which is necessary for me as the final jql search I use will be too complex to define in the URI.

I am using this curl command:

```
curl -D- -u username:password -o output.json -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "@query.json" "https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/latest/search"
```

query.json contains the following search parameters:

```
{"jql":"project = PCO and status = Onboarded","maxResults":3,"fields":["Sumary","lead","Cost Centre"]}
```

The response I'm getting looks like this:

```
{
"expand": "schema names",
"StartAt": 0,
"maxResults": 3,
"total": 294,
"issues": [{
    "expand:operations,versionRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
    "id": "123456",
    "self": "https:/jira...",
    "key": "ABC-123"
}, {
    "expand:operations,versionRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
    "id": "456789",
    "self": "https:/jira...",
    "key": "ABC-456"
}, {
    "expand:operations,versionRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
    "id": "456123",
    "self": "https:/jira...",
    "key": "ABC-321"
}]
}
```